# SharePoint Online Sign in and password does not match issue in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, powershell-2.0, csom, multi-factor-authentication

I'm trying to connect to SharePoint Online but I'm getting this error and not 100% sure why so I would be really appreciated if I can get any help or suggestion why it might be.

I believe it might have to do with my tenant using MFA so just wondering how can I connect/login using MFA?.

```
#Variables
$SiteURL = "https://companyName-my.sharepoint.com/personal/yzqpsn_nam_corp_m_com"
$ServerRelativeUrl= "documents/Testing"
 
Try {
    #Get Credentials to connect
    $Cred= Get-Credential
 
    #Setup the context
    $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
    $Ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)
   
    #Get the web from URL
    $Web = $Ctx.web
    $Ctx.Load($Web)
    $Ctx.executeQuery()
 
    #Get the Folder object by Server Relative URL
    $Folder = $Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($ServerRelativeUrl)
    $Ctx.Load($Folder)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
 
    #Call the function to empty Folder
    Empty-SPOFolder $Folder
 
    #Delete the given Folder itself
    Write-host  -f Green "Deleting Folder:"$Folder.ServerRelativeUrl
    $Folder.Recycle() | Out-Null
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
}
Catch {
    write-host -f Red "Error:" $_.Exception.Message
}
```

[image]

Comment: According to the constructor of [SharePointOnlineCredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.-ctor?view=sharepoint-csom#microsoft-sharepoint-client-sharepointonlinecredentials-ctor(system-string-system-string)), seems like it's expecting `string`, `string` there is no mention about `securestring`.

Comment: Instead of using the User name and password, you can use App ID & Password: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/03/connect-pnponline-with-appid-and-appsecret.html